# Polymer in ASP.net 5

Tags: asp.net-core, polymer, visual-studio-community

Trying to make a custom polymer element in ASP.NET 5 in Visual Studio Community. I select "New Project"->"Web"->ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core). In Solution Explorer I add a new file "*helloworld.html*", in this file I create a new polymer element with this code:

```
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="hello-world">
    <style></style>
    <template>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "hello-world"
    });
</script>
```

Next I try to implement (add) this element to the DOM that is created by ASP.NET 5, so I make changes in those two files *index.cshtml* and *_layout.cshtml*.

The file *index.cshtml* is:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";    
}

<link rel="import" href="~/helloworld.html"/> 

<div class="row">
    <hello-world></hello-world>
</div>
```

In *_layout.cshtml* I add two lines of code:

```
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
```

Next I click debug but no Hello World on the screen. Only header and footer from _layout.cshtml

Comment: In "Application Insights Request GET", while debugging, there is note: _response code 404_. And a red diamond is next to it.

Comment: Please don't use ASP.NET 5 tag, it's not called like this anymore. It's ASP.NET Core and bears the version of 1.0.*

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
<link rel="import" href="~/helloworld.html"/>
```

must be outside the { ... }

If not, take a look at the source HTML code and, using F12 (IE/Chrome... debugger), see Network tab for errors.

Comment: I didn't know how to edit the question. The code you wrote is outside the {...}, as for Network errors I wrote this error below the question: " 
       
 
In "Application Insights Request GET", while debugging, there is note: response code 404. Can't find/import _helloworld.html_ file  "

Comment: reedit the question - the code you wrote is outside the {...}

Comment: Where did you put helloworld.html file?It must be in wwwroot folder to work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what already has been suggested. Are you sure that

```
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
<script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
```

are in the right place? Load the page, open the developer tools (F12) and in the HTML/DOM view/explorer check that these lines actually appear in the `<head>` tag of the loaded page. The default ASP.NET Core template contains `<environment>` tags in _Layout.cshtml. In my test with your code I first put the links into the wrong environment. Now it works for me.